# C++ linker error after overloading an operator

Tags: xcode, linker, g++, overloading, operator-keyword

I keep getting the following error when I try to compile an example program from C++ how to program, Deitel and Deitel. I used **g++ Fig11_05.cpp -o Fig11_05**

I spent hours trying to solve this problem by looking up the Internet and particularly stackoverflow, but with no avail!

I tried using different command line arguments such as -libstd=libc++, -std=c++11, -std=c++14

the error I keep getting is as this:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, PhoneNumber const&)", referenced from:
      _main in Fig11_05-1f04bd.o
  "operator>>(std::__1::basic_istream >&, PhoneNumber&)", referenced from:
      _main in Fig11_05-1f04bd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The result of **g++ -v**:

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

The codes:

```
// Fig. 11.3: PhoneNumber.h                                                                                                                                   
// PhoneNumber class definition                                                                                                                               
#ifndef PHONENUMBER_H
#define PHONENUMBER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class PhoneNumber
{
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const PhoneNumber&);
  friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream&, PhoneNumber&);
private:
  std::string areaCode; // 3-digit area code                                                                                                                  
  std::string exchange; // 3-digit exchange                                                                                                                   
  std::string line; // 4-digit line                                                                                                                           
}; // end class PhoneNumber                                                                                                                                   

#endif

// Fig. 11.4: PhoneNumber.cpp                                                                                                                                 
// Overloaded stream insertion and stream extraction operators                                                                                                
// for class PhoneNumber.                                                                                                                                     
#include <iomanip>
#include "PhoneNumber.h"
using namespace std;

// overloaded stream insertion operator; cannot be                                                                                                            
// a member function if we would like to invoke it with                                                                                                       
// cout << somePhoneNumber;                                                                                                                                   
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const PhoneNumber& number)
{
   output << "Area Code: "  << number.areaCode << "\nExchange: "
          << number.exchange << "\nLine: " << number.line << "\n"
          << "(" << number.areaCode << ") " << number.exchange << "-"
          << number.line << "\n";;
   return output; // enables cout << a << b << c;                                                                                                             
} // end function operator<<                                                                                                                                  

// overloaded stream extraction operator; cannot be                                                                                                           
// a member function if we would like to invoke it with                                                                                                       
// cin >> somePhoneNumber;                                                                                                                                    
istream& operator>>(istream& input, PhoneNumber& number)
{
   input.ignore(); // skip (                                                                                                                                  
   input >> setw(3) >> number.areaCode; // input area code                                                                                                    
   input.ignore(2); // skip ) and space                                                                                                                       
   input >> setw(3) >> number.exchange; // input exchange                                                                                                     
   input.ignore(); // skip dash (-)                                                                                                                           
   input >> setw(4) >> number.line; // input line                                                                                                             
   return input; // enables cin >> a >> b >> c;                                                                                                               
} // end function operator>>   


// Fig. 11.5: fig11_05.cpp                                                                                                                                    
// Demonstrating class PhoneNumber's overloaded stream insertion                                                                                              
// and stream extraction operators.                                                                                                                           
#include <iostream>
#include "PhoneNumber.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   PhoneNumber phone; // create object phone                                                                                                                  

   cout << "Enter phone number in the form (123) 456-7890:" << endl;

   // cin >> phone invokes operator>> by implicitly issuing                                                                                                   
   // the global function call operator>>( cin, phone )                                                                                                       
   cin >> phone;

   cout << "\nThe phone number entered was:\n";

   // cout << phone invokes operator<< by implicitly issuing                                                                                                  
   // the global function call operator<<( cout, phone )                                                                                                      
   cout << phone << endl;
} // end main
```

**Note:** I recently installed then uninstalled CUDA toolkit 8. I needed a newer version of Xcode, so I installed Xcode the newest version 8.2.1, and kept the old version in a different directory just in case. I don't think the problem is with the installation of Xcode though. Also when I installed CUDA I had to set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to a directory. However, it might not be the source of the problem! I am just trying to help you figure out the problem to help me fix it :)

**Thank you in advance! You are such a good community!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt to build the program:

```
g++ Fig11_05.cpp -o Fig11_05
```

is unsuccessful because you have neglected to compile and link into the
program the code that contains the definitions of the functions:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const PhoneNumber& number)
```

and:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, PhoneNumber& number)
```

which are called by your program. That is why the linker says:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: 
"operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, PhoneNumber const&)", referenced from: _main in Fig11_05-1f04bd.o 
"operator>>(std::__1::basic_istream >&, PhoneNumber&)", referenced from: _main in Fig11_05-1f04bd.o 
...
```

Do this instead:

```
g++ Fig11_05.cpp PhoneNumber.cpp -o Fig11_05
```

Or to spell out the process in full:-

Compile source file `Fig11_05.cpp` to object file `Fig11_05.o`:

```
$ g++ -o Fig11_05.o -c Fig11_05.cpp
```

Compile source file `PhoneNumber.cpp` to object file `PhoneNumber.o`:

```
$ g++ -o PhoneNumber.o -c PhoneNumber.cpp
```

Link the object files `Fig11_05.o` and `PhoneNumber.o` into program `Fig11_05`

```
$ g++ -o Fig11_05 Fig11_05.o PhoneNumber.o
```

You can then run:

```
./Fig11_05
```

Here is [a fairly good beginner's tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)
about building C or C++ programs with GCC.

Comment: Thank you! I came from a java programming background where I would only run the file with main after compiling other files.

Comment: @maneeVictorious You're welcome. To say "thanks" on Stackoverflow, please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)